# Send Struct of floats over UDP

Tags: python, c, struct, floating-point, udp

So I have a Struct of floats in `Python` that I send over `UDP`:

```
lat = 14.566545
lon = 13.435456
alt = 3.5657732

coord_struct = struct.pack('fff', lat, lon, alt)
udp_sock.sendto(coord_struct,(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT_SEND))
```

To a program written in `C` that is supposed to receive the struct and work with it:

```
typedef struct coords{ 
         float latitude; 
         float longitude; 
         float altitude;
} GEO_POS;

GEO_POS coord_struct;

recv_len = recvfrom(udp_fd, coord_struct, sizeof(coord_struct), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, &si_slen);

printf("lat: %f; lon: %f; alt: %f", coord_struct.latitude, coord_struct.longitude, coord_struct.altitude);
```

But the data that is received is wrong, for example: `47.88980` is received as `5469892474000000000000000`.

Do I need to serialize the `struct` in order to send it, if yes how?

Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First problem I see here is that your `coords` struct in C is defined as being composed on three `real64` variables. If that `64` stands for 64 bits (so basically a `double`), that's a problem: the `f` specifier of `struct.pack` means 32 bit `float`, not 64 bit. You should add the definition of `real64` to your question.

Comment: Ok did not know that the f specifies a 32 bit float. For testing I could just use float on in the C program too. And later try it with real64. Will change my question to that.

Comment: Another problem is that sending data over a network usually requires transforming everything to network endianness (that is big endian) and then back to the needed endianness when receiving. If these programs are running on different machines which have different endianness that will result in the wrong values being received. Conversions are done using `htonl/htons` for sending and `ntohl/ntohs` for receiving in C and using the `!` specifier of `struct.pack` in Python (e.g. `!f`).

Comment: Oh, seems like there is a lot more to `struct.pack` then I thought, thanks! I totaly forgot about the byte orders, I looked up some example codes and they did not use it either so I forgot it.  I will give it a try.

Comment: Hm, Im sadly still receiving gibberish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a `&` sign in front of `coord_struct` in the call to `recvfrom`. Secondly...

The correct way of sending binary data over the network is to convert everything to network endianness (big endian) when sending and back to host endianness when receiving.

Sending in Python:

```
lat = 14.566545
lon = 13.435456
alt = 3.5657732

coord_struct = struct.pack('!fff', lat, lon, alt)
# Notice the ! sign for network endianness.

udp_sock.sendto(coord_struct, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT_SEND))
```

Receiving in C:

```
struct coords { 
    float latitude; 
    float longitude; 
    float altitude;
};

struct coords coord_struct;
ssize_t recv_len;

// Assuming you have already correctly initialized the socket.

errno = 0;
recv_len = recvfrom(udp_fd, &coord_struct, sizeof(coord_struct), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &si_other, &si_slen);
// IMPORTANT ---------------^ notice the & here.

if (errno) {
    // There was an error with recvfrom, print it to
    // stderr to see what's wrong.
    perror("recvfrom failed");
    exit(1);
}

// Also check recv_len here, if recv_len < sizeof(coord_struct) you need
// to retry everything or try receiving more data.

// Convert from network endian to host endian:
coord_struct.latitude  = ntohl((uint32_t)coord_struct.latitude );
coord_struct.longitude = ntohl((uint32_t)coord_struct.longitude);
coord_struct.altitude  = ntohl((uint32_t)coord_struct.altitude );

printf(
    "lat: %f; lon: %f; alt: %f\n",
    coord_struct.latitude,
    coord_struct.longitude,
    coord_struct.altitude
);
```

Additionally, you might also want to use `MSG_WAITALL` when calling `recvfrom` just to have less chance of receiving less data than expected. Even though the struct you are sending shouldn't cause much trouble since it's very small and will basically always fit in a single UDP datagram.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is working now, cant belief it was such a simple mistake. When I use `ntohl` I only reseive integer values (with and without `uint32_t`), but when I dont use `ntol` its working perfectly!